# Is the determinant of a matrix preserved under permutations of the rows/columns of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is the determinant of a matrix preserved under permutations of the rows/columns of the matrix?

If not, is its absolute value preserved?

Comment: May I ask what do you mean by permutation of the rows?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Any single exchange of two rows or two column changes the sign of the determinant.  You need to keep track of whether you do an odd or even number of switches of rows or columns.  That is to say, you need to multiply the determinant by $\mathbb{sgn}(\sigma)$, the sign of the permutation $\sigma$ for any given row or column permutation.

Comment: i believe you meant $sgn(\sigma)$ for $(-1)^\sigma$

Comment: Thanks @Anjan3, i'll fix that, you can also do edit suggestions when you see these :)

Comment: your answer is so nice . it cleared my doubt at once ...:-)